# CSS: override parent element color

Tags: css

I have a navigation bar that consists of horizontal list elements that have an outer container and element class they are a part of. They all have same properties, but I just want to have one of list elements (#nav_user) to have a different color from the rest. The outer container (nav_item_container) determines the color of the list element. If I add another child with the new color, such as I did with #nav_user , the color does not fill the entire block, only a horizontal line equal to size of the text changes. Adding "style = background-color" in the div seems to fix that. But is there a better way to do this? I hope that made sense. Thanks for any help.

EDIT: add fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/h4ecB/

```
<ul>
    <li>
        <div class="nav_item_container">
            <div class="nav_element">
                <div id ="nav_user">
                    Item with different color here
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </li>
</ul>

<div id ="nav_links">
    <ul>
        <li><div class ="nav_item_container"><div class ="nav_element"> Item1 </div></div></li>
        <li><div class ="nav_item_container"><div class ="nav_element"> Item2 </div></div></li>
        <li><div class ="nav_item_container"><div class ="nav_element"> Item3 </div></div></li>
    </ul>
</div>          

li .nav_item_container .nav_element #nav_user{
    background-color: #FFBF00;
}

li{
    display: inline-block;
    list-style-type: none;
}

li .nav_item_container{
    display: table;
    overflow: hidden;
    height: 45px;
    min-width: 100px;
    background-color: #FF0000;
}

li .nav_item_container .nav_element{
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: middle;
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0 auto;
    text-align: center;
    color: #FFFFFF;
}
```

Comment: can you please add fiddle

Comment: i have made a fiddle from your code http://jsfiddle.net/HjAHh/ . but i still did not get your problem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If i understand what you mean. You need to give `#nav_user` the full height, for the background, and then a `line-height` of the same amount of the height to get it vertical centered.

```
#nav_user {
   ....
   height:45px;
   line-height:45px;
}
```

Check [JsFiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/a3GcM/1/)